# Cannot pass dynamically map style in angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

i have an issue.
I'm getting styles dynamically from a services. Styles are arrays and check that all worked ok when added inline but when i'm getting the data dynamically the map renders the default styling.

For example here's my code:

```
 var styleArray = data.settings.Theme.mapSelected;
 if(data.settings.Theme.mapSelected != undefined) {
    $scope.mapOptions = {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      styles: styleArray
    };
 } else {
    $scope.mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    styles: [{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":65},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":51},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":30},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":40},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-100}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"hue":"#ffff00"},{"lightness":-25},{"saturation":-97}]}]
                    };
                  }
```

And here my html

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='settings.Location.coords' zoom='12' options='mapOptions' doRebuildAll="true">
    <ui-gmap-marker idKey='settings.Content._id' coords='settings.marker.coords'></ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I'm getting correctly the data as i can see in the inspector when i log into console but map is not rendering the selected style array but google's default.

Any ideas?

ps: the if else statement works correctly, and also all the options as well only style array is not.

update: if i pass the dynamic style array inline it works, only with variable it doesn't. i tryid to pass the data directly (data.settings.Theme.mapSelected) but it does the some thing.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KtvcIoqTaa9HHG5Xc1E6?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was quite simple...

As the data was json angular wasn't render correctly the information, so the simple solution is to covert data with **[angular.fromJson()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)**.

So the correction is just edit the imported data like this:

```
var styleArray = angular.fromJson(data.settings.Theme.mapSelected);
```

And it will work.