# How to change the color of land, and water of google maps with angular?

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using this angular component for google maps https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core . I swear one day I thought I saw that you can change the color of water, and land with this. But when I look at the documentation I dont see that. Is it possible to change the color of land and water on a google map with this angular module? If so how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps Javascript API has documentation on [how to style your map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

Agm also surfaces the same `styles` property. You can find that in their [documentation](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/components/AgmMap.html#styles)

So depending on how you instantiate your agm map, all you have to do is pass an array with the custom style settings to your agm map component.

Using the plunker agm demo as a base, and if creating a custom component just add `[styles]= "styles"` in the component's `template` like so:

```
<sebm-google-map 
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [disableDefaultUI]="false"
  [zoomControl]="false"
  (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)"
  [styles]= "styles">
```

Then declare your `styles` array like so:

```
styles: any[] = [
  {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
  {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
  {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
]
```

See the actual plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jlxycMowMxxpkiruY2FQ?p=preview) (just insert your own API key over at @NgModule setup)

You can even pass dynamic map styles. See this [related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487638/cannot-pass-dynamically-map-style-in-angular-google-maps)